# Why does jQuery change only fires once inside load function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, onload

I am having a div what loads a form, and i would like to to load the form url with the data when it it changed, but it only fires once

My code

```
$( "#calculator-wrapper" ).load( "mysite.com/new2/kalkulator/index.php", function(data) {
    $('#calculator').change(function(){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();    
        $("#calculator-wrapper").load("mysite.com/new2/kalkulator/index.php?"+formData+'&sub=Sz%C3%A1mol');
    });    
});
```

It works, but only once, i am a beginner so im stuck for a second, i tried to use `bind()` and `on()` but that does not work either.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need event delegation for change event.try this:

```
$( "#calculator-wrapper" ).load( "mysite.com/new2/kalkulator/index.php", function(data) {
$(document).on("change",'#calculator',function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $( "#calculator-wrapper" ).load("mysite.com/new2/kalkulator/index.php?"+formData+'&sub=Sz%C3%A1mol');
});});
```

Comment: OP must have used  `$('#calculator').on('change',function(){` which is not going to work for delegated elements.

Comment: ah thank you, i did not know i need to use $(document), thank you now it works, i will accept your answer, i just need to wait 7 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).on("change","#calculator",function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();    
    $("#calculator-wrapper").load("mysite.com/new2/kalkulator/index.php?"+formData+'&sub=Sz%C3%A1mol');
});
```

Because you need delegation for dynamically created objects.

Comment: @Neel $('#calculator').on("change" is different my friend

Comment: why did you down voted him? i used on yes, but not with $(document) he was right